# How can I avoid a foreach loop in a situation where I need data from more than one table linked to each other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I'm working on a relationship / friend system in PHP as a backend for my app and I'm wondering if there is any way I can avoid a foreach loop in PHP by using MySQL instead to handle the filtering. See code below.

MySQL table `users`
[image: Text]

MySQL table `relationships`
[image: Text]

My PHP code, see // HERE for the foreach loop in question.

```
<?php
$userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];
$response = array();
$friends = array();

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE user_id_a = ? OR user_id_b = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $userid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          if ($row['user_id_a'] != $userid) {
            // Add $row to array
            $tmp = array(
              'userid'=>$row['user_id_a'],
              'status'=>$row['status']
            );
            $friends[] = $tmp;
          }
          if ($row['user_id_b'] != $userid) {
            // Add $row to array
            $tmp = array(
              'userid'=>$row['user_id_b'],
              'status'=>$row['status']
            );
            $friends[] = $tmp;
          }
        }
        $response['friends'] = $friends;

        // HERE, I LOOP TROUGH THE ARRAY $response['friends'] to fetch additional information from the users table

    foreach ($response['friends'] as $key => $value) {
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, profileimage FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
          $stmt->bind_param("s", $value['userid']); // $value['userid'] is the UserID from the array
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $stmt->bind_result($username, $profileimage);
          $stmt->fetch();

          $tmp = array(
            'userid'=>$value['userid'],
            'username'=>$username,
            'profileimage'=>$profileimage,
            'status'=>$value['status']
          );
          $friends[] = $tmp;
        }

?>
```

with the current solution I have, having 100 friends means that I have to make 100 queries which doesnt sound good to me.. can I avoid this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a conditional `join`:

```
select r.* , u.*
from relationships r
inner join users u 
    on u.user_id = case when r.user_id_a = ? then r.user_id_b else r.user_id_a end
where ? in (r.user_id_a, r.user_id_b)
```

The idea is to retrieve the information of the "other" user. The `case` expression somehow mimics the behavior of the `if` statements in your php code.

Both question marks should be replaced with the same parameter, that represents the user whose friends you want to display.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to be honest with you, I'm terrible at MySQL and its expressions!
.. with your suggestion of using a conditional join, would this mean that I can still loop through the results to populate my array? Eg: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {} ?

Comment: yes you can, your reesultset only has now more column that you can get

Comment: This is just amazing. I had no idea MySQL had so much logic implemented. I really have to read up on this. Thank you!